Spresense SDK スタートガイド (IDE 版)を実行したときに、setupファイルが生成されません。
参照しているサイト
https://developer.sony.com/spresense/development-guides/sdk_set_up_ide_ja.html
こちらの2.1.3Windows11(WSL2)向けセットアップを順番に実行し、
source ~/spresenseenv/setup

をUbuntu上で実行すると、
-bash: /home/masa/spresenseenv/setup: No such file or directory

と表示されます。
ディレクトリを確認してみると、spresenseenvディレクトリの中には、windowsというフォルダがあるだけで、setupが確認できませんでした。
原因が不明で困っております。
原因解明のお手伝い、または、spresenseenv/setup 内の内容を教えていただけると幸いです。

2.1.3. の 2. に書かれたコマンド
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sonydevworld/spresense/master/install-tools.sh bash install-tools.sh  を実行された際に、エラーは出ていませんでしたか？
もし出ていなければ「出ていない」とお知らせください。
もし出ていたなら、エラー内容の記載をお願いします。

エラーは出ていませんでした。念の為帰ってきたものを記載しておきます。

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sonydevworld/spresense/master/install-tools.sh
Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)... 185.199.108.133, 185.199.109.133, 185.199.110.133, ...
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|185.199.108.133|:443...cconnected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 10383 (10K) [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘install-tools.sh’
install-tools.sh        100%[============================>]  10.14K  --.-KB/s    in 0.001s
2024-10-09 17:01:55 (17.9 MB/s) - ‘install-tools.sh’ saved [10383/10383]

ありがとうございます。
記載していただいた内容は、2.1.3.の2.のコマンドの1行目 wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sonydevworld/spresense/master/install-tools.sh の結果のように見えます。
2行目のコマンド bash install-tools.sh の実行結果はいかがでしょうか？

E: Unable to locate package libncurses5
cp: cannot stat 'openocd-0.11.0-spr1-20230313/*': No such file or directory
の2つのエラーが表示されていました。

shell上で、uname -m　とコマンド打った結果はどうなりますか？
x86_64　や　aarch64　であればファイルがあると思いますが。。

x86_64でした。。。

私も同様にインストール途中で止まっていましたが、unzipをインストールしたら解決しました。
同様の状況であればいいのですが・・・
参考:
Linux環境にZip, Unzipをインストールする - Qiita

ファイルのダウンロードに失敗しているのではないかと思います。
bash install-tools.sh では以下３つのファイルを落としているようで、
下2つはx86_64環境でのファイルになります。
・nuttx-tools.tar.gz
・gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.10-x86_64-linux.tar.bz2
・openocd-0.11.0-spr1-20230313-win64.zip
openocd-0.11.0-spr1-20230313-win64.zip　がファイルがないとのエラーが出ているようですが、他の２つは存在していますか？
openocdを例にすると、エラーが出ているopenocdは以下のコマンドのものを落とすようです。
curl -L https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-openocd-prebuilt/releases/download/v0.11.0-spr1/openocd-0.11.0-spr1-20230313-linux64.tar.bz2 > openocd-0.11.0-spr1-20230313-linux64.tar.bz2

このコマンドで落とせない場合は、会社などのネットワーク利用でプロキシ設定ができていないとか、お使いのネットワーク環境の問題があるかもしれません。切り分けが必要だと思います。
